# css width browser specific way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix the elements inside the body even when they are minimized. I set body width as

`<body style="width:1553px;">`
This width works well for chrome while for IE it is not aligned properly. When I give

```
width:auto
```

upon minimizing the browser, elements get misaligned.Any ways to give browser specific width so that I get proper alignment in the screen and also it should work when I minimize the screen ?

Comment: do you reset the browser styles first..?

Comment: Have a look at Bootstrap Responsive Web Framework http://getbootstrap.com/.

Comment: Is there a misspelling in `widht:1553px` (`widht` instead of `width`)?

Comment: @user2584538 no i don't rest !

Comment: May be you should look at `min-width` property or you could hook the css media queries. As suggested above use bootstrap or foundation css.

Comment: Use css reset first. As well why don't you use width: 100%; instead of width: auto;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change `widht` to `width` and apply `width` to the immediate child `div`(child of `body`) with `margin` to get it in center like,

```
<body>
   <div style="width:1553px;margin:0 auto">
      .....
      .....    
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using this way, U can do..
Reference:http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-create-browser-specific-css-rules-styles.html#gref

> ```
> For Internet Explorer (version 10+):
> ```

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    body {width:1553px;}
}
```

> ```
> For Google Chrome (version 28+):
> ```

```
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {
    body {width:1553px;}
}
```

> ```
> For Mozilla Firefox (all versions):
> ```

```
_:-moz-tree-row(hover), body {
          width:1553px;
    }
```